# How to fit an int list to a desired function

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy, curve-fitting

I have an int list `x`, like `[43, 43, 46, ....., 487, 496, 502]`(just for example)
`x` is a list of word count, I want change a list of word count to a list penalty score when training a text classification model.

I'd like use a **curve** function(maybe like math.log?) use to map value from x to y, and I need the min value in x(`43`) mapping to y(`0.8`), and the max value in x(`502`) to  y(`0.08`), the other values in x map to a y follow the function.

For example:

```
x = [43, 43, 46, ....., 487, 496, 502]

y_bounds = [0.8, 0.08]

def creat_curve_func(x, y_bounds, curve_shape='log'):
    ...

func = creat_curve_func(x, y)

assert func(43) == 0.8
assert func(502) == 0.08
func(46)
>>> 0.78652 (just a fake result for example)
func(479)
>>> 0.097 (just a fake result for example)
```

I quickly found that I have to try some parameter by my self to get a **curve** function fit my purpose, try again and again.

Then I try to find a lib to do such work,  [scipy.optimize.curve_fit](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) turns out. But it need three parameter at least: f(the function I want to generate), xdata, ydata(I only have **y bounds**:0.8, 0.08),  only xdata I have.

Is there any good sulotion?

**update**

I think this is easy unserstood so didn't write the fail code of `curve_fit`.Is this the reason of down vote?

**The reason that why I can't just use curve_fit**

```
x = sorted([43, 43, 46, ....., 487, 496, 502])
y = np.linspace(0.8, 0.08, len(x)) # can not set y as this way which lead to the wrong result
def func(x, a, b):
    return a * x +b # I want a curve function in fact, linear is simple to understand here
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y)

func(42, *popt)
0.47056348146450089 # I want 0.8 here
```

Comment: I don't understand your question - is your problem just that when you call your function with values outside the range of your original `x` array, you want it to return the min (or max) of `x`?

Comment: @Nils Gudat I want a mapping function. it keep x bounds`(42, 502 )`  point to y bounds `(0.8, 0.08)`, and mapping the others value in x to corresponding value by the mapping function.

Comment: So you want to fit some curve approximately to the data, but with the extra constaint that the end points lie exactly on the curve?

Comment: Also, are you sure your y bounds are linear and not logarithmic? I might be inclined to use `y = np.logspace`, but to answer that I'd need to know where x came from

Comment: @Eric Yes!  y bounds can be any curve, maybe logarithmic too.The English words in the field of mathematics is hard to understand, I just check the dictionary,I think logarithmic is included in curve, but linear is not.x is a word count list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this way?

EDIT: added weights. If you don't need to put your end points exactly on the curve you could use weights:

```
import scipy.optimize as opti
import numpy as np

xdata = np.array([43, 56, 234, 502], float)
ydata = np.linspace(0.8, 0.08, len(xdata))
weights = np.ones_like(xdata, float)
weights[0] = 0.001
weights[-1] = 0.001

def fun(x, a, b, z):
    return np.log(z/x + a) + b

popt, pcov = opti.curve_fit(fun, xdata, ydata, sigma=weights)

print fun(xdata, *popt)
>>> [ 0.79999994  ...  0.08000009]
```

EDIT:
You can also play with these parameters, of course:

```
import scipy.optimize as opti
import numpy as np

xdata = np.array([43, 56, 234, 502], float)
xdata = np.round(np.sort(np.random.rand(100) * (502-43) + 43))
ydata = np.linspace(0.8, 0.08, len(xdata))
weights = np.ones_like(xdata, float)
weights[0] = 0.00001
weights[-1] = 0.00001

def fun(x, a, b, z):
    return np.log(z/x + a) + b

popt, pcov = opti.curve_fit(fun, xdata, ydata, sigma=weights)

print fun(xdata, *popt)
>>>[ 0.8     ...    0.08      ]
```

Comment: I am sorry, I think  the question is very clearly when I post it... I have update the question.

Comment: I didn't realize that could use weights to make the start and end point as close as possible to my required value! Thanks you !